# enable select when an option is selected, setting disable to false not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I want a script that will enable the *Address* and *Department* dropdowns when the *Organisaion Name* dropdown is selected.

[image: Here is what ive got currently]

my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Department1, #Address1').attr('disabled',true);
    $('#Organisation1').keyup(function(){
        if($(this).val().length !=0)
            $('#Department1, #Address1').attr('disabled', false);
        else
            $('#Department1, #Address1').attr('disabled',true);
    })
});
```

Here is the markup for the Department Field.

```
<div class="control-group">
   <label class="control-label">Department</label>
   <div class="controls">
      <div class="input-append input-prepend">
         <input type="text" class="input-xxlarge" id="Department1" >
         <button type="button" class="btn" href=""> Find</button>
      </div>
      <span class="help-inline"><i class="help" title="Enter the Department of this Opportunity.">Help</i></span>
   </div>
</div>
```

FULL CODE

```
 <style>
.schools-position{
    position: relative;
    top: 3px;
    left: 3px;
}

    .groups{
        width: 100%;
    }

    .groups tr{
        text-align: center;

    }

    .groups th{
            border-top: 0;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    background-image: url(../../_assets/img/grid/header.png);
    background-position: top left;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 0px 6px;
    height: 28px;
    line-height: 28px;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
</style>


   <div class="uiModalHeader clearfix">
    <h1 class="title jobs"><span class="light">Opportunities :</span> Sandwich</h1>
</div>
<form class="form form-horizontal">
    <div class="uiModalBody clearfix">

         <ul id="NewOpps_Tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" style="position:absolute;left:10px;right:10px;top:10px;">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#NewOpps_tab1"><i class="icon list"></i>General</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

       <div class="tab-content" style="position:absolute;bottom:10px;left:10px;right:10px;top:48px;border:#ddd 1px solid;border-top:0;padding:20px 20px;margin-bottom:0 !important;overflow-y:scroll;">


        <fieldset>

            <legend>About this Opportunity</legend>

            <div class="control-group required">
                <label class="control-label">Organisation Name <em>*</em></label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <div class="input-append input-prepend">
                        <input type="text" class="input-xxlarge" id="Organisation1">
                        <button type="button" class="btn" href=""> Find</button>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Department</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <div class="input-append input-prepend">
                        <input type="text" class="input-xxlarge " id="Department1" >
                        <button type="button" class="btn" href=""> Find</button>
                    </div>
                    <span class="help-inline"><i class="help" title="Enter the Department of this Opportunity.">Help</i></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Address</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <div class="input-append input-prepend">

                        <input type="text" class="input-xxlarge" id="Address1" >
                        <button type="button" class="btn" href=""> Find</button>

                    </div>
                    <span class="help-inline"><i class="help" title="Enter the Address for this Opportunity.">Help</i></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <hr />

            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Level</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <select class="input-xxlarge" id="Level">
                        <option>-- Please Select --</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="PLCMNT">PLCMNT</option>
                        <option value="OTHER">OTHER</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Academic Year</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <select class="input-xxlarge" id="Academic Year">
                        <option>-- Please Select --</option>
                        <option value="2019/20">2019/20</option>
                        <optio vaue="2018/19">2018/19</optio>
                        <option value="2017/18">2017/18</option>
                        <option value="2016/17" selected="">2016/17</option>
                        <option value="2015/16">2015/16</option>
                        <option value="2014/15">2014/15</option>
                        <option value="2013/12">2013/12</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Vacancies</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <textarea rows="2" cols="20">

                    </textarea>
                    <span class="help-inline"><i class="help" title="Enter the Vacancies for this Opportunity.">Help</i></span>
                </div>
            </div>

           <div class="control-group required">
                <label class="control-label">Source<em>*</em></label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <select class="input-xxlarge" id="Academic Year">
                        <option>-- Please Select --</option>
                        <option value="Student Found" selected="selected">Student Found</option>
                        <option value="University Found">University Found</option>
                        <option value="Alumni Relationship">Alumni Relationship</option>
                        <option value="School Relationship">School Relationship</option>
                        <option value="Found on Website">Found on Website</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <hr />

            <div class="control-group required">
                <label class="control-label">Job Title <em>*</em></label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <div class="input-append input-prepend">
                        <input type="text" class="input-xxlarge" id="Job-Title">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Job Description</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <div class="input-append input-prepend">
                       <textarea rows="5" class="input-xxlarge txtStage1">

                       </textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group required">
                <label class="control-label">Duration <em>*</em></label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <div class="input-append input-prepend">
                        <input type="text" class="input-xxlarge" id="Duration">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group required">
                <label class="control-label">Duration Measure <em>*</em></label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <select class="input-xxlarge" id="Duration-Measure">
                        <option>-- Please Select --</option>
                        <option value="Days">Days</option>
                        <option value="Weeks">Weeks</option>
                        <option value="Months">Months</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Salary</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <div class="input-append input-prepend">
                        <input type="text" class="input-xxlarge" id="Salary">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

              <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Working Hours</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <div class="input-append input-prepend">
                        <textarea class="input-xxlarge">

                        </textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <hr />

            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Category</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <select class="input-xxlarge" id="Category">
                        <option>-- Please Select --</option>
                        <option value="1">Accountancy, Banking and Finance</option>
                        <option value="2">Animal and Plant Resource</option>
                        <option value="3">Business, Consulting and Management</option>
                        <option value="4">Charity and Voluntary Work</option>
                        <option value="5">Creative Arts and Design</option>
                        <option value="6">Energy and Utilities</option>
                        <option value="7">Engineering and Manufacturing</option>
                        <option value="8">Enviromemt amd Agriculture</option>
                        <option value="9">Healthcare</option>
                        <option value="10">Hospitality and Events Management</option>
                        <option value="11">Information, Research and Analysis</option>
                        <option value="12">Insurance and Pensions</option>
                        <option value="13">Law</option>
                        <option value="14">Law Enforcement and Security</option>
                        <option value="15">Leisure, Sport and Tourism</option>
                        <option value="16">Marketing, Advertising and PR</option>
                        <option value="17">Media and Internet</option>
                        <option value="18">Performing Arts</option>
                        <option value="19">Property and Construction</option>
                        <option value="20">Public Services and Administration</option>
                        <option value="21">Publishing and Journalism</option>
                        <option value="22">Recruitment and HR</option>
                        <option value="23">Retail</option>
                        <option value="24">Sales</option>
                        <option value="25">Science and Pharmaceuticals</option>
                        <option value="26">Social Care</option>
                        <option value="27">Teaching and Education</option>
                        <option value="28">Transport and Logistics</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
        </div>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Nearest Train or Tube Station</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <select class="input-xxlarge" id="Category">
                        <option>-- Please Select --</option>
                        <option value="Test 1">Test 1</option>
                        <option value="Test 2">Test 2</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>


             <div class="control-group required">
                <label class="control-label">Placement Type Offered<em>*</em></label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <select class="input-xxlarge" id="Placment-Type-Offered">
                        <option>-- Please Select --</option>
                        <option value="Placement Year">Placement Year</option>
                        <option value="Internship">Internship</option>
                        <option value="Convention de Stage">Convention de Stage</option>
                        <option value="Work Study">Work Study</option>
                        <option value="Social Work 1">Social Work 1</option>
                        <option value="Social Work 2">Social Work 2</option>
                        <option value="Social Work 3">Social Work 3</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

        </fieldset>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="uiModalButtons clearfix">
        <div class="pull-right">
             <div class="btn-group">
                <button class="uiButton"><span class="icon cancel">Cancel</span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <a class="uiAjaxModal" href="<?php echo $appurl; ?>../../Admin/Things2/stage2.php"><button class="uiButton"><span class="icon save">Next</span></button></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>





<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#Department1, #Address1').attr('disabled',true);
        $('#Organisation1').change(function(){
            if($(this).val() !='')
                $('#Department1, #Address1').removeAttr('disabled');
            else
                $('#Department1, #Address1').attr('disabled','disabled');
        });
    });


$(document).ready(function() {

   $(document).on("keypress", "#Organisation", function(){
     if($("#Organisation").val() !=0 || $("#Organisation").val()!=NULL)
       {
         $("#Department").removeAttr("disabled");
         $("#Address").removeAttr("disabled");
       }
      else
       {
         $("#Department").attr("disabled",true);
         $("#Address").attr("disabled",true);
      }
  });



        $('#Organisation1').select2({
        data: [{
                id: "1",
                text: "Organisation 1"
            }, {
                id: "2",
                text: "Organisation 2"
            }, {
                id: "3",
                text: "Organisation 3"
            }, {
                id: "4",
                text: "Organisation 4"
            }],
        multiple: false,
        placeholder: '-- Please Select',
        allowClear: true
    });

    $('#Department1').select2({
        data: [{
                id: "1",
                text: "Department 1"
            }, {
                id: "2",
                text: "Department 2"
            }, {
                id: "3",
                text: "Department 3"
            }, {
                id: "4",
                text: "Department 4"
            }],
        multiple: false,
        placeholder: '-- Please Select',
        allowClear: true
    });

        $('#Address1').select2({
        data: [{
                id: "1",
                text: "Address 1"
            }, {
                id: "2",
                text: "Address 2"
            }, {
                id: "3",
                text: "Address 3"
            }, {
                id: "4",
                text: "Address 4"
            }],
        multiple: false,
        placeholder: '-- Please Select',
        allowClear: true
    });




    $('#select-all').click(function(event) {
  if(this.checked) {
      // Iterate each checkbox
      $('.schools-check').each(function() {
          this.checked = true;
      });
  }
  else {
    $('.schools-check').each(function() {
          this.checked = false;
      });
  }
});  


    $('.choose').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.uiModalContent').html('').addClass('loading');
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('href'),
            success: function(data) {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('.uiModalContent').removeClass('loading');
                    $('.uiModalContent').html(data);
                }, 500);
            }
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

Here is the code for that entire modal

Comment: To enable, or disabled a select2, it is better to call select2's methods such as `$('select').select2().enable(false);`

Comment: element with #Department1 is an input of type text and not select (dropdown)

Answer (score 1):

use `removeAttr()` instead of setting the disabled attr to `false`

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var els = $('#Department1, #Address1');

    els.attr('disabled',true);

    $('#Organisation1').change(function(){
            $(this).val() ? els.removeAttr('disabled') : els.attr('disabled', '');

        });
});
```

https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attributes

> The presence of a boolean attribute on an element represents the true
>   value, and the absence of the attribute represents the false value.

Comment: doesnt work. Address and Department stay disabled. they need to become enabled when ive selected an option in Organisation name

Comment: do i keep my first line of the script when trying to implement this code?

Comment: still doesnt work, ive fiddled around with it but im not getting the result i want. the department field and address field to enable when am option is selected from the organisation name field

Answer (score 0):

if Organization is select box then you can enable/disable based on organization select change:

```
 $('#Organisation1').change(function(){
           if($(this).val() !='')
               $('#Department1, #Address1').removeAttr('disabled');
           else
               $('#Department1, #Address1').attr('disabled','disabled');
 });
```

Comment: For both cases you do the same thing?

Comment: doesnt work. Address and Department stay disabled. they need to become enabled when ive selected an option in Organisation name

Comment: still doesnt work. Department and Address stay disabled when they shouldnt

Answer (score -1):

```js
$('#Organisation1').blur(function() {
  if ($(this).val() != '')
    $('#Department1, #Address1').removeAttr('disabled')
  else
    $('#Department1, #Address1').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
})
```